# Returning Records from last 6 Months with SELECT

Tags: oracle

Lets say I have a Table of all people born this year and last year,
How can I only Select the ones of the past 6 months?

I have tried this but it didn't work:

```
   Select * From table WHERE DateColumn >= now()-interval 6 month;
```

i got following error:

```
ORA-00904: "NOW": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier
```

The Data Type is Time-stamped.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think something like this might work:

```
Select * From table 
WHERE 
DateColumn >= add_months(sysdate, -6);
```